# Controling and getting feedback for robots in Blender

Tags: python, scripting, external-applications, network

Is it possible to control, and get feedback for robots in Blender using the python API?

I'd like to have proxy objects in Blender, that I can control, that will control my reallife robot, but also will mirror the actions of the real life robots. I would like to use wifi to send the information, and the robot would use either an Arduino or Raspberry Pi.

Is it possible to do this in Blender using Python, and if so, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: Should be possible, although I think you'll need external libraries.

Comment: I just edited your answer to try to make it a bit cleaner to read. Could you look through it to make sure that I kept it consistent with what you're asking? Thanks! :)

Comment: Why don't you come over to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm) and I'll answer your question over there. We generally want to keep the comments clean of extra questions like this. Just for future reference :)

Comment: [Any post can be edited by anyone](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/editing). However edits made by users with less than 1000 reputation will be reviewed by other users before being made public.

Comment: Search google for  "python serial robot" IIRC there have been several posts on blenderartists.org regarding controlling robots either using the game engine or bpy.